# What does the 1/w coordinate stand for in gl_FragCoord?

Tags: opengl, fragment-shader

The gl_FragCoord variable stores four components: (x, y, z, **1/w**)

What is the **w** coordinate and why is it stored as **1/w**?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The GLSL and OpenGL specifications are needlessly confusing in this regard. The OpenGL spec is easier to understand: `gl_FragCoord` stores the X, Y, and Z components of the window-space vertex position. The X, Y, and Z values are calculated as described for computing the window-space position (though the pixel-center and upper-left origin can modify the X and Y values). This is described in the `Coordinate Transforms` section of the spec.

The W component of `gl_FragCoord` is (1 / W<sub>c</sub>), where W<sub>c</sub> is the *clip-space* vertex position. It's `gl_Position.w` from your vertex shader.

The only useful purpose for keeping W<sub>c</sub> around is to [reverse-transform `gl_FragCoord`](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Compute_eye_space_from_window_space) to get the clip-space position back. Which, as that page shows, requires multiplying by W<sub>c</sub>. But since `gl_FragCoord` only stores the inverse of this value, it now requires dividing by `gl_FragCoord.w`.

Therefore, we can assume that OpenGL stores it this way because OpenGL isn't allowed to make too much sense ;) See, it's a rule that every part of the OpenGL specification must have something that's a bit nonsensical. The XYZ components made too much sense, so they decided to have it stores the inverse of the value you actually want.

OK, technically this is a historical artifact from the days when 3D Labs created GLSL. I'm sure they did it for purely selfish hardware reasons, but I have no real proof of that.

Comment: You said OpenGL always have something a bit nonsensical. I just was confused why OpenGL's default NDC z range is [-1, 1]. We know that mapping far clip plane z to NDC's z=0 is good for preventing z-flighting problems. Is this the 'something' a bit nonsensical? Or is there some advantages to use [-1, 1]?

Comment: @lotsofone: "*We know that mapping far clip plane z to NDC's z=0 is good for preventing z-flighting problems.*" It is when your GPU does floating-point computations when dealing with Z positions. It doesn't matter in a world where GPUs keep *maybe* 16-bits of integer precision of Z values in the internal registers used for depth testing. In such a world, the range is irrelevant. So you may as well pick the one that gives NDC space a cubic shape: [-1, 1] for X, Y, and Z.

Answer (score 2):

A homogeneous coordinate is given by: **(x, y, z, w)**, which projects to: **(x/w, y/w, z/w)**. `gl_FragCoord` stores this projection, but rather than storing the (useless) **(w/w) = (1)** for the last component, it stores **(1/w)**, to preserve useful information.

Comment: "`gl_FragCoord` stores this projection" No, it stores a post projection transform of that into window-space.